# Cargar una imagen en jsf con javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

Quiero cargar una imagen con javascript ya que la imagen se genera del lado servidor y nesecito en el momento que se crea cargarla del lado cliente en jsf con glassfish

Comment: mira cómo preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Bienvenido Richar, como te dice David para que puedas entender como funciona el sito lee [tour], para que entendamos mejor la pregunta agrega el codigo